# Does remove persistent store @ run time is the best choice?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

My core data design  need to

1) Must have 2 persistent stores .

One for Permanent Database.
Two for User'sCreation.

2) Both pstore based on the Same MODEL . And same Context.

3) I have 2 ViewControllers ,
   One for showing  Permanent Database , Two for showing User's Creation.

Problem is when i need to FETCH .sqlite.

It fetched entity named  @"Car" from both PStore 1 and PStore 2.

I want to fetch only @"Car" from PStore 1.  And avoid getting data from PStore 2.

Does .  [psc removePersistentStore...]; Is good solution to switching between PStore1 - PStore 2  ?? thanks.

Comment: No, specify the [affectedStores](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506518-affectedstores) for the fetchRequest.

Comment: wow thanks alot and much and many and more !